# Conditionally defining C function macros

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I am wondering how I can conditionally define function macros. For instance, suppose I have a function macro called `SETBIT`. I would like to define my own version of it should someone using my library not include a separate header file where such a macro function would have already been defined. The reason for this is portability among different compilers.

So, I know that I can do this with constants as follows:

```
#ifndef X
#define X 10
#endif
```

I would like to do something similar with a function macro

```
#ifndef SETBIT
#define SETBIT(port,bit) ((port) |= (1 << (bit)))
#endif
```

However, I don't believe this will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I don't believe this will work.

What leads you to believe that? It will work (provided that you fix the typo - it should read `#ifndef SET_BIT`, I suppose).

Comment: Yes, it did work. I guess I figured that I needed the "function parameters" somewhere. doh!